# My xxxhdpi emulator for android shows blank screen

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on an android app in Xamarin right now. I am about 95% done I would say. The only thing that's left is trying to get the emulator for the xxxhdpi (Nexus 6, LG G4, etc) to work. It only shows a black screen during start up.

I have my different drawable and value folders for the different dpi-denisties, and they all seem to work perfectly fine except for the xxxhdpi.

I'm fairly new to android development and stackoverflow, keep that in mind.

Comment: how long did you wait until it is finished with loading? Do you have HAXM enabled (only for windows and intel i chips)? I guess it needs a very long time to load the emulator with xxxhdpi...

Comment: The emulator loads fairly quickly, but then it just shows a black screen no matter how long I wait. 
Edit: I have a AMD laptop btw

Comment: try to create emulator for Nexus 6 or Nexus 6P, they have xxxhdpi

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be the upscaling of the drawable/values xxxhdpi folders. The textviews got WAY to big to fit the screen for some reason so I downscaled them.